# Android ActivityTest with multiple sets of conditions

Tags: android, testing, installation, conditional-statements

I want to know the best practice for following scenario:

I've got an Activity which establishes a connection to a server. Therefore I can have three different states: Trying to connect, connection established and connection not possible. These states are displayed in a TextView.

In my TestActivity I want to check if the TextView shows the correct message according to the connection state. How do I accomplish this? For all I know, I can set my conditions in the setUp() method. But what if I want to test different conditions? Do I need one TestActivity for each scenario or is there a better and more elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can add several test in the same test class if they need the same conditions established in the setUp() method. A trick that you can use to differentiate them is use the alphabetical order:

```
testAConnecting()
{
}

testBConnectionOK()
{
}

textCConnectionKO()
{
}
```

Comment: that is the point! the conditions are not the same. So I need different TestActivities?

Comment: what do you mean with that the conditions are different? When I say "same conditions" I mean execution conditions, the same activity for example. To test the three different states that you say, you can change the condition for each test in the same test.

Comment: by different conditions i mean this: i've got my connection object which either has an established connection or not. i thought i had to initialize this object in the setUp() method. 
but if i can change the conditions in the test itself (i thought this was bad practice) it should not be a problem.
thank you!

Comment: yes, seems not a good practice but this is what I had to do in my experience. If not, I should create hundreds of classes. I hope another one can help us with a better approach :)